# Variable that contains different value for each loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, variables

I would like to download prices from the internet. The concept works, when I define `symb` as a constant value (e.g. K15). But now, I want to download data from different links, where the part `symb` changes according to the value of the cells G13 to G22 in my spreadsheet. (In other words, I want to go through each row from G13 to G22 - each containing a different value for `symb` - and download the data from the respective link).

I tried that with a simple loop, defining the variable `symb` in each one of the loops:

```
For i = 1 To 10

    Symb = Worksheets("Futures").Range("G12").Offset(i, 0).Value

Set qt = querysheet.QueryTables.Add( _
Connection:="URL;" & "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" & Symb & ".cbt&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgv&e=.csv", _
    Destination:=querysheet.Cells(5 + i, 1))

Next i
```

Obviously, it doesn't work like this. I assume that it is not possible to define a variable within the loop, is it? Can somebody give me a hint how I can make that work?

Comment: It's not at all obvious that it doesn't work like this. What do you mean by "It doesn't work"? Do you get an error? If so, which line raises the error and what does the error message say? If no error, please describe how the observed results diverge from what you expect.

Comment: You may want to do simply : `Destination:=querySheet.Cells(5, 1))` because adding each qt will automatically insert the column.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! VBA does not disply an error message, but the result that I get is just ".cbt,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A". Before, when I just had one constant value for symb, I got something like "CK15.cbt,376.25,"3/31/2015","2:09pm",-18.25,394.00,398.50,375.75,302825"

Comment: There's something wrong with your URL string. When I enter that URL manually in my browser (Chrome) it downloads a CSV file which displays just the N/A as before. You're missing something in that string, which is causing the tables to return N/A values.

Comment: Yes, you are right! I adjusted that (I forgot a letter in the spreadsheet cells), and now the download works again. The problem that remains is that I only get the value from the last loop. Looks like the current loop overwrites the loop from before. Do you have an idea how to handle that?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's something worng with your Connection String.  When I get rid of the `.cbt` in the URL string, it works. Or, you may have forgotten to include some letters, so debug it in your browser and get the Connection string correct and it should work.

You may also want to modify the destination, like so, and refresh the table:

```
Set qt = querySheet.QueryTables.Add( _
Connection:="URL;" & "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" & Symb & "&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgv&e=.csv", _
    Destination:=querySheet.Cells(5, 1))
    qt.Refresh
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a possibility that the querytable is not completed from right to left but from left to right? Right now it seems like every new cell pushes the value from the loop before to the right. That means, the value from the last loop is in A5, whereas the value from the first (out of 6 loops) is found in F5.

Comment: Adding the QT will insert to existing data, which is why you're seeing what you're seeing. Without going back and trying the code again, try maybe: `Destination:=querySheet.Cells(5, i)`.  That should put the first one in Column 1, the second in Column 2, etc.

Answer (score 0):

you could use an array like this

```
    symb(1 to 10) as String
    for i=1 to 10 
        symb(i)=cells(i,1)
    next i
```